# Use different settings file for testing

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-settings

I have a django application with settings.py file. By default, my django application takes this file but, for tests I need another settings.py file (tests/settings_test.py for example).

I'm using unittest for testing.

My question: How can I configure my tests for use tests/settings_test.py file instead of the default settings.py file?

test_mytest.py

```
import unittest
import os
import sys
class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):

....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] # It shows 'myappication.settings'
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myappication.tests.settings")
    print os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] # It shows 'myappication.settings' and I think it should show 'myappication.tests.settings'
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options:
1. Environment variable https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
2. Configure https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#custom-default-settings
So either set environment variable before running tests or import settings and configure them in your test suite.

Comment: I've tried that option, but it doesn't work for me. I've updated my post with more info.